Powershell: Cant call 'Get-SecOpsOverridePolicy' after successfully authentication to Exchange online
I have the following issue after my code has been working without issues for a long time in production. Nothing new has been installed lately.
After successfully connecting to Exchange Online using PowerShell and trying to get the SecOpsOverridePolicy.
Get-SecOpsOverridePolicy -Identity "SecOpsOverridePolicy"

I get the following error.
Get-SecOpsOverridePolicy: The term 'Get-SecOpsOverridePolicy' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I connect to the system using (as admin) as follows
$connData = @{
            ConnectionUri = "https://ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/PowerShell-LiveId"
            AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
            AccessToken = "SECRET123"
            Organization = "myorg.onmicrosoft.com"
        }

Connect-ExchangeOnline @connData 

What puzzles me is that I can see that ExchangeOnlineManagement (tried both version 3.4.0 and 3.5.0)  doesn't include the cmdlet above
 Get-Command -Module ExchangeOnlineManagement      

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Connect-ExchangeOnline                             3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Function        Connect-IPPSSession                                3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Function        Disconnect-ExchangeOnline                          3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Function        Get-WrappedCommand                                 3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Function        IsCloudShellEnvironment                            3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Function        UpdateImplicitRemotingHandler                      3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Add-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy                        3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-ConnectionInformation                          3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig                    3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-DefaultTenantMyAnalyticsFeatureConfig          3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOCasMailbox                                  3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMailbox                                     3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission                     3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics                     3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMailboxPermission                           3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMailboxStatistics                           3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXOMobileDeviceStatistics                      3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXORecipient                                   3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-EXORecipientPermission                         3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-MyAnalyticsFeatureConfig                       3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-UserBriefingConfig                             3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-VivaFeatureCategory                            3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-VivaInsightsSettings                           3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-VivaModuleFeature                              3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-VivaModuleFeatureEnablement                    3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Get-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy                        3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Remove-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy                     3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Set-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig                    3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Set-DefaultTenantMyAnalyticsFeatureConfig          3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Set-MyAnalyticsFeatureConfig                       3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Set-UserBriefingConfig                             3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Set-VivaInsightsSettings                           3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement
Cmdlet          Update-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy                     3.5.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement


Environment info:
PSVersion: [7.4.1]
PSEdition: [Core]
OS: [Amazon Linux 2023.3.20240304]
Platform: [Unix]
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: [2.3]
SerializationVersion: [1.1.0.1]
ExchangeOnlineManagement: [3.4.0]
Token details:
"roles": ["Exchange.ManageAsApp"]

After A comment from #lit I also double-checked that ExchangePowerShell module is installed.
Install-Module -Name ExchangePowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Get-Module -ListAvailable                                

    Directory: /Users/hraman/.local/share/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
...
Script     3.5.0                 ExchangeOnlineManagement            Desk      {Add-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy, Get-ConnectionInformation, Get-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig, Get-DefaultTenantMyAnalyti…
Script     3.4.0                 ExchangeOnlineManagement            Desk      {Add-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy, Get-ConnectionInformation, Get-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig, Get-DefaultTenantMyAnalyti…
Script     0.11.0                ExchangePowerShell                  Desk      {Clear-EPAutoMapping, Clear-EPExchangeLogs, Convert-EPIMCEAEXtoX500, Get-EPMaintenanceMode…}

Get-Command -Module ExchangePowerShell


Notice how the last command doesn't return any output.
Where does this cmdlet should come from?
Does Microsoft do/try todo some runtime loading of this module during the connection?

From the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-secopsoverridepolicy?view=exchange-ps, it appears to be in the ExchangePowerShell module.

Thanks I try to add the module but it doesn't work, see my updates to the question

See the following comment from the link you shared. "For Exchange Online, Security & Compliance, and Exchange Online Protection, the module from the PowerShell Gallery that you use to connect is ExchangeOnlineManagement"
